# Running a selenium python script on a on a remote computer

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am working on python script for an automation but the script has to run every day at 10 PM
Currently, i have to launch it on my own computer which is a problem.
I am wondering if it would be possible to maybe rent a remote computer or have a virtual machine that could run the script everyday.

One of my problem is that I think that it is necessary that the computer has a graphic interface (but I am not sure)

Thank you

Comment: Your question is very broad. I suggest you add more and precise detail what exactly you want to achieve. Apart from that I recommend you look into cloud functions like [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) that can be triggered with a cron pattern.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.